# create JSON key of second level to lowercase in javascript / nodej s

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes, tolower

I am trying to make json key to lowercase so I got a solution where it making all the json key toLowercase but I don't want to make all the json key to lower case I only want to make the second level of json key to the lowercase

so while doing `console.log(data)` I am getting this output

```
{
  'valueToBeAssign': {
    titleAsName: 'random title',
    urlOrWebsite: 'www.google.com',
    name: 'english',
    number: 123
  }
}

{
  'computerAssignTask': {
    taskName: 'debug every thing',
    issueGenerated: 'At low level',
    assigneName: 'Mick',
    reporterName: 'Pete',
    issueResolve: 'not yet'
  }
}
```

so I wrote a code

```
          let json = JSON.stringify(data);
          var newJson = json.replace(/"([\w]+)":/g, function ($0, $1) {
            return '"' + $1.toLowerCase() + '":';
          });
          var newObj = JSON.parse(newJson);
          console.log(newObj);
```

but by this I am getting all the key in lowercase

```
{
  'valuetobeassign': {
    titleasname: 'random title',
    urlorwebsite: 'www.google.com',
    name: 'english',
    number: 123
  }
}

{
  'computerassigntask': {
    taskname: 'debug every thing',
    issuegenerated: 'At low level',
    assignename: 'Mick',
    reportername: 'Pete',
    issueresolve: 'not yet'
  }
}
```

what I actual want is the first key should not be changed but after that it should be changed like this

```
{
  'valueToBeAssign': {
    titleasname: 'random title',
    urloOrwebsite: 'www.google.com',
    name: 'english',
    number: 123
  }
}

{
  'computerAssignTask': {
    taskname: 'debug every thing',
    issuegenerated: 'At low level',
    assignename: 'Mick',
    reportername: 'Pete',
    issueresolve: 'not yet'
  }
}
```

I want it in this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to iterate through all the keys of the object. That way, you can discriminately alter the keys by level.

```js
const data = {
  'valueToBeAssign': {
    titleAsName: 'random title',
    urlOrWebsite: 'www.google.com',
    name: 'english',
    number: 123
  }
}

const newData = {}
for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
  newData[key] = {}
  for (const innerKey of Object.keys(data[key])) {
    newData[key][innerKey.toLowerCase()] = data[key][innerKey]
  }
}

console.log(newData)
```